# Изменить вывод результата

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

t=$TEST_COUNTER        #took from "export TEST_COUNTER=3"
COUNTER=1234567890

for ((i=0 ; i<=$t ; ))
do
    echo $((i+COUNTER)) ; sleep 0.5
    i=$((i+1))
    b=$(($COUNTER+$i))

done
```

*Запуск скрипта*

> $ ./loop2.sh

- 1234567890
- 1234567891
- 1234567892
- 1234567893

*Хочу преобразовать вывод так чтоб он выводил последовательно друг за другом*

> ./loop2.sh

- 12345678901
- 123456789012
- 1234567890123

Comment: `echo ${COUNTER}${i}; COUNTER=${COUNTER}${i}`

Comment: Спасибо, получилось)

Comment: Инкремент можно добавить сразу в цикл `for ((i=0 ; i<=$t ; i++ ))` тогда вот эта часть `i=$((i+1))` будет не нужна. А дописать в конец переменной можно `COUNTER+="$i"`

Comment: @ipatev_nn Да, спасибо, так и сделал)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
t=$TEST_COUNTER        #took from "export TEST_COUNTER=3"
COUNTER=1234567890

#переносим инкремент в условия цикла
for ((i=0;i<=$t;i++))
do
#Вариант от @aleksandr-barakin
    #COUNTER=${COUNTER}${i}
#Вариант от меня
    #COUNTER+=${i}
    echo $COUNTER
    sleep 0.5
done
```

Ответ отмечен как **общий**